# How to Improve Performance with Spark Streaming Against S3

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, spark-streaming

I have a Spark Streaming job that is using `streamContext.textFileStream("s3://log-directory/")` to listen for files and then parse them and output them as ORC files. This particular directory has a lot of files streaming in - over 40 files every 5 minutes.

However, no matter how many machines I add on my EMR cluster, it seems to stall at having between 3 and 4 executors at any given time, running a max of 30 tasks. This makes the job fall behind quite quickly, because each microbatch job takes about 5 minutes to parse and convert all the data, and it's only parsing between 4-10 log files at a time. Ideally, each batch would process all 40+ files in that five minutes, then move onto the next set, basically keeping pace with the stream.

So, my question - is there a way to increase the number of running executors? Or is there some other problem I haven't thought of that would allow my job to keep pace with new files? I've read a few things about how S3 can be quite slow with Spark, but my job keeps returning messages like 
`17/04/21 19:14:32 INFO FileInputDStream: Finding new files took 2135 ms`. This isn't *fast* but it's also not 5 minutes, so I feel like it's not a problem with finding files. As for environment, I currently set `spark.maximizeResourceAllocation=true` as a config option, which results in:

```
spark.default.parallelism = 160
spark.executors.cores =     8
spark.executor.memory =     10356M
```

This seems like it should be sufficient as well - the files are currently maxing out at 100mb each. I appreicate any help you can give, and happy to add more details if necessary.

Comment: what is the source of the Streaming? Kinesis? Kafka? Files?

Comment: Files from an Amazon ELB

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem of Archtecture,

Using spark to take the information from an ELB and write the information direct in Orc is not the best solution at all.

The write process is slow with orc due to compression, and IO to the disk. What I suggest you is to change the process, create a job in Spark to write your data to the Kinesis or Kafka to be a fast write. In the other side of the process, if you are using Kinesis you can use the FireHose to write your data in your S3 or even the Spark to write in S3 with a stream process with a bigger window of time.

If you want to take your data fast, to your fast data or something I suggest you to use Presto or Athena from AWS to take the data direct from Kinesis. Or other tool that you need.

I hope this can help.

Comment: My data source is the ELB logs - they contain a bunch of information that is valuable to us. And Presto is ultimately the tool I'm using to query, but its performance is far improved when reading ORC over text files. So, my idea was to stream the files written by ELB directly to ORC, rather than having a batch job (my current solution). I don't see a way to get the logdata into Kinesis from the ELB?

Comment: There is a bunch of solutions, one that I already used and I recommend for a similar issue that you have is the FluentD http://docs.fluentd.org/v0.12/articles/kinesis-stream There is a great Issue to write data into Orc is the IO. And about performance with orc, yes this is a HUGE performance reading from Orc. The point is, what is your necessity of the Real Time Data? Kinesis can help you to take the read faster than from file in ELB. Take a try to that. I suggest ELB -> FluentD -> Kinesis -> Spark -> S3(Orc)

Answer (score 0):

Spark's FileInputDStream is very inefficient in the way it scans directories; it ends up scanning every file multiple times to get the timestamp and see if it can be excluded. This surfaces against any object store where the GET request to get a timestamp of a file takes 100+ms.

The best thing you can do right now (until SPARK-17159 gets in) is to keep that directory free of any old files you have already processed. They aren't needed, yet they still keep being scanned, slowing down your program the more there are.